# Can I Load Window After Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a custom Modal Box (just like the browser's `alert()`)

Usually, using `alert()` the browser pauses that underneath page rendering and executions,

**how to get the same behavior** of restricting the rest of the window to load unless one `confirms OK` in the Modal element?

So how to

> Pause window load -> Show modal -> (OK) -> continue window load

Comment: *`I've got a popup form in HTML (just like default chrome alert('yeah'))`* ? What you mean? What is a *Popup form*? Any code to share?

Comment: äh. what? please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: If you mean you've a custom alert using a div or another element, the answer is no, you can't create a real modal "pop-up" with JS and HTML (except by using native DOM methods ofcourse, including [`showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog)).

Comment: why not just a normal `confirm` popup?

Comment: I've given certain styles to it. Yes, its a simply a div box which I want to convert in a popup which loads like alert() feature of browsers.

Comment: I can smell an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202792) here, why you want to delay loading, usually people are intending to do something on the contrary.

Comment: OP, this isn't an ideal solution to your problem. I cannot imagine any reason to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MehulMohan Actually this should be easy: Just code the modal in the `body` only, and when user clicks `OK`, load the rest of the content with AJAX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New Edit

Instead of stopping page load, why not remove all of the page show popup, then place the document back ie using JQuery...

```
var pageBody = $('body').html(); //Copies Body of Page
pageBody = $('body').html(""); //Delete the Body
/* Do Some Awesome Code here*/
$('body').html(pageBody); //Place Body Back
```

This will allow page to load, remove it, execute code then place it back. The other method below will not work as stopping the page, will stop **EVERYTHING** including any other code you are running.

## Old Answer

You could use

```
window.stop(); //works in all browsers but IE    
if ($.browser.msie) {document.execCommand("Stop");}; //works in IE,
```

document.execCommand works in IE, however it does stop some of FF, NS and some other browsers' functions. Like displaying GIF's animation for example. Using "if browser is IE" makes these two codes work perfectly in all browsers.

---

This code will simply pause the execution of the page. Like clicking the STOP button on your page but you will need to reload to start the page again..

I would personally advise simply placing a fullscreen white div behind your popup box but above your popup to give the idea of the popup is only there while the user will be none the  wiser that the rest of the page has stopped loading

Comment: Then how to continue loading?

Comment: ^ yep, how do I continue

Comment: Updated with another solution

Comment: Hmm... If the OP's "alert-box" is in the `head` `$('body')` doesn't exist, if it's in `body`, execution will get stuck on "alert-box"...

Comment: Cool. But it still shows a glance of the page if I place it in $(document).ready(); And If I don't use document.ready, I guess DOM would not be ready to be manipulated, right?

Comment: @MehulMohan Haha, if  you place this code into `$(document).ready()`, it's too late, the whole DOM has already been loaded, no need to try to prevent loading anymore...

Comment: @Teemu than you use CSS `body{visibility:hidden;}` and on DOM ready you turn it magically ON

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What's the point to ask to prevent loading then? In the comment thread of the OP, there's my comment about xy-problem though.

Comment: @DeanMeehan Teemu is right, by the time DOM is ready all the page was visible for a fraction of time. CSS might help (see my comment above to reflect your A. edit), but I'd rather not suggest anything like that at all :)

Comment: @MehulMohan What's your point, you can hide the whole body with a simple CSS: `body{display: none;}`, and then show it again when user clicks `OK` in your "alert-box"...

Comment: @Teemu `display:none;` is not good, cause it might crash some element calculations in other JS functions. Use like I suggested (was for a reason) `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm sorry, somehow I've already forgotten that your comment. You're right, there's no need for an expensive remove/return `body` operation, if this would be enough.

Comment: I actually didn't think of CSS, but my approach actually will remove the code from the DOM (Stops people looking at source to see contents)  and @MehulMohan you can use window.onpaint and attach to the body tag to run before it laods